# Thread error in Python & PyQt

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I noticed that when the function [setModel](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.0/qabstractitemview.html#setModel) is executed in parallel thread (I tried threading.Timer or threading.thread), I get this:

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QHeaderView(0x1c93ed0), parent's thread is QThread(0xb179c0), current thread is QThread(0x23dce38)
QObject::startTimer: timers cannot be started from another thread
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QTreeView(0xc65060), parent's thread is QThread(0xb179c0), current thread is QThread(0x23dce38)
QObject::startTimer: timers cannot be started from another thread
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: That's a very bad title for a very valid question. Why not calling it something like "How to multithread in Python & PyQt"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed a fact of life that multithreaded use of Qt (and other rich frameworks) is a delicate and difficult job, requiring explicit attention and care -- see [Qt's docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads.html) for an excellent coverage of the subject (for readers experienced in threading in general, with suggested readings for those who yet aren't).

If you possibly can, I would suggest what I always suggest as the soundest architecture for threading in Python: let each subsystem be owned and used by a single dedicated thread; communicate among threads via instances of `Queue.Queue`, i.e.,  by message passing. This approach can be a bit restrictive, but it provides a good foundation on which specifically identified and carefully architected exceptions (based on thread pools, occasional new threads being spawned, locks, condition variables, and other such finicky things;-). In the latter category I would also classify Qt-specific things such as cross-thread signal/slot communication via [queued connections](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've stumped on a Qt limitation there. Try using signals or events if you need objects to communicate across threads.

Or ask the Qt folk about this. It doesn't seem specific to PyQt.