# PyQt4: timers cannot be started from another thread

Tags: python, multithreading, progress-bar, pyqt4

When I run the following code ...

```
import sys, time
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class WorkThread(QtCore.QThread):
 def __init__(self):
  QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

 def run(self):
  for i in range(100):
   time.sleep(1) # artificial time delay
   print(i)
   test.pbar.setValue(i)
  return


class MyApp(QtGui.QWidget):
 def __init__(self):
  QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, None)
  self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 600)
  self.setWindowTitle('threads')
  self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
  self.pbar = QtGui.QProgressBar(self)
  self.layout.addWidget(self.pbar)



# run
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
test = MyApp()
workThread = WorkThread()
workThread.start()
test.show()
app.exec_()
```

I get the following error ...

```
QObject::startTimer: timers cannot be started from another thread
```

The code still continues to execute ok, but what I dont understand is **why this error stops appearing after I remove `test.pbar.setValue(i)`** OR replace pbar with a different widget such as a list. It seems obvious that the error is specific to the progressbar widget ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Thread error in Python & PyQt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434831/thread-error-in-python-pyqt)

Comment: If a progressbar is the cause of his error then maybe it's related ... but his specific error was not addressed, only good clean code was suggested. I have posted my code in the hope of getting a more specific answer.

Comment: Rhys: it's the same cause though. You're mixing between threads - accessing an object created in one thread, directly from another. This is trouble - and Qt even says it explicitly. A progress bar is probably creating a timer, while a list does not, which is the cause of the specific error you're seeing. In any case, *don't do that* is the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the error you're seeing provides you exactly with the information it was meant to provide. You are not allowed to invoke `QObject::setTimer` from a thread different from the one in which the timer was created. Specifically, one version of the code of `QObject` I found has this code:

```
int QObject::startTimer(int interval)
{
    Q_D(QObject);

    if (interval < 0) {
        qWarning("QObject::startTimer: QTimer cannot have a negative interval");
        return 0;
    }

    d->pendTimer = true;                                // set timer flag

    if (!d->threadData->eventDispatcher) {
        qWarning("QObject::startTimer: QTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread");
        return 0;
    }
    return d->threadData->eventDispatcher->registerTimer(interval, this);
}
```

Note the warning-generating code.

Calling the `pbar.setValue` method obviously makes a call to this `startTimer` method, which creates the warning.

Now, I'm not sure what your problem with this is? Do you absolutely need to control the progress bar directly from another thread? That's not a good idea.

Comment: The way I have structured my program (too large to post) is that I first setup the GUI and then start ONE Qthread which does all the programs 'thinking' ... I have to do this otherwise the GUI freezes. Executing the pbar.setValue outside of where all the 'thinking' is taking place doesn't seem right to me. Question: the program still runs after the error ... can I just turn if off and ignore it?

Comment: after spending a few hours learning signals, emits and restructuring massive amounts of code ... I got it to work without displaying the warning message. However this has made a new warning message on termination of the program. So ... the code is vastly more complicated, redundant and difficult to read ... and all I've done is replaced one warning message with another. I've decided to cut my losses and revert the code above

Comment: @Rhys: perhaps you should just ask (probably in a separate question) about the actual problem you need to solve - try to boil it down to the simplest explanation possible - you may just get a good suggestion for a design that will cleanly solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for you help. I have fixed all the errors. The error posted in this question was solved by using signals and emits. The second error i spoke of above was due to not using self. inside a thread. So all is solved. Thanks for your support (and being patient with my frustration!)

Comment: ```Do you absolutely need to control the progress bar directly from another thread? That's not a good idea.``` This doesn't make anysense. I have 100% made a project that does this and works 100% fine. Now I have made another that is very similar but I'm getting the same error. It is so weird.